# $v,w\in V$ are nonzero vectors s.t. $(v,w)=0$. Define $T:V\to V$ as: $\forall u\in V$.$T(u)=(u,v)w+(u,w)v.$ Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, inner-products

**Problem**: Let $V$ denote an inner product vector space over the field $F .$ Let $v, w \in V$ be two nonzero vectors such that $(v, w)=0$. Define the map $T: V \rightarrow V$ as follows. For all $u \in V$ set $T(u)=(u, v) w+(u, w) v .$ Find all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T .$

**Attempt**:
$ Tv = (v,v)w + (v,w)v = (v,v)w = ||v||^2 w $
$ Tw = (w,v)w + (w,w)v = (w,w)v = ||w||^2 v $
Since $ v,w \neq 0_V $ then $ \frac{Tw}{||w||^2} = v $ , $ \frac{Tv}{||v||^2} = w $
So $ T^2v = ||w||^2 ||v||^2 v $, $ T^2w = ||w||^2 ||v||^2 w $ ( by plugging that last two equations into each other )
Hence $ ||w||\cdot||v|| $ is an eigenvalue of $ T $ with the corresponding eigenvector $v,w $ and $ v=w $ [ Now's the problem : since $ v=w $ then from the assumption that $ (v,w) = 0 $ then $ (v,v) =0 $ and $ v=w=0 $ but this is a contradiction to the given that $v,w \neq 0_V $. ]

**Questions:**

1. How did I get the contradiction that $v=w = 0_V $? what did I do wrong in my attempted proof?
2. Given the failed attempt, how would one prove the above? I don't have any other ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose that $\dim V=n$ is finite. I would start by this: try to write $T$ using a clever basis. $v,w$ are orthogonal. You can extend them to an orthogonal basis $v,w,v_3, \dots , v_n$. Then, what is the matrix form of $T$?

Comment: @Crostul Diagonal matrix? in that case there'll be  at-least $2 $ different eigenvalues

Comment: You can't conclude that $Tv = \|w\| \|v\| v$ from $T^2v = \|w\|^2\|v\|^2 v$, as you seem to be assuming.

Comment: @TheoBendit Why not? I used the theorem "If $ A  $ is a square matrix s.t. $ A^2 $ has eigenvalue $ \lambda^2 $ then $ A $ has eigenvalue $ \lambda $ or $-\lambda$". So $ Tv = \|w\| \|v\| v $ or $ Tv = - \|w\| \|v\| v $ and in either case I'll get that $v $ is a linear combination of $ w $ which will be a contradiction.

Comment: Ok I think I've got it, It has to be the case that $ \|w\| \|v\| $ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $ v$ and $ - \|w\| \|v\| $ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $w $ ( or the other way around ) ( and  $ \|w\| \|v\| $ cannot be the eigenvalue corresponding to both since that'll give me a contradiction ). Is this correct?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 There's still steps missing. Yes, $A$ must have $\|v\|\|w\|$ **or** $-\|v\|\|w\|$ as an eigenvalue (it need not be both), but it doesn't imply $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors! For example, the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ squares to give the identity, and $v = (1, 0)$ and $w = (0, 1)$ are orthogonal vectors such that $A^2 v = v$ and $A^2w = w$, but $Av$ and $Aw$ are not parallel to $v$ and $w$ respectively.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks, now it makes much more sense. The theorem "If A is a square matrix s.t. $A^2$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^2$ then $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$ or $ - \lambda $" does not tell me anything about the corresponding eigenvectors. So if $v$ was the corresponding eigenvector for $ \lambda^2 $ under $ T^2 $ then although $ \lambda $ or $ - \lambda $ are eigenvalues of $ T $ I can't be guaranteed that $ v $ will be an remain an eigenvector of $ T $.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take $v=w$ since they are orthogonal and non-zero. You have to find $a$ and $b$ such that $av+bw$ is an eigen vector corresponding to the eigen value $\|v\|\|w\|$. This works out to  $\|v\|w+\|w\|v$. Similarly, $\|w\|v-\|v\|w $ is an eigen vector corresponding to eigen value $-\|v\|\|w\|$. Also any vector orthogonal to $v$ and $w$ is an eigen vector corresponding to eigen value $0$. The set of all eigen values is $\{\pm \|v\|\|w\|,0\}$ unless the space is two dimensional, in  which case $0$ is not an eigen value.